# How do I read in "9999-12-31" as NA using pandas' read_excel?

Tags: python

I have an excel file that I want to read into python where in the date columns "9999-12-31" is used to represent missing values.

Ideally I want to already convert those values into NA when I read in the data so I try this.

`df = pd.read_excel('sales_data.xlsx', na_values = '9999-12-31')`

However, when I look at the data afterwards it comes out as "9999-12-31 00:00:00" rather than NA.

Am I doing something wrong here or is there a better way to handle the NA conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Give values like a list :

```
na_values = ['9999-12-31']
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to make any difference when I try it.